# Move native phpmyadmin databases to xampp

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

After a computer crash (Mac OSX Update), I was able to recover my files from a back up.  In order to make things easier on me in the future, I decided to move to XAMPP instead of using the native PHPMyAdmin and MySQL.  I know where PHPMyAdmin was pointing before - how do I move the files so XAMPP can see them?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a recommended means of backing up and restoring, but as long as there's nothing in the XAMPP databases you might just be able to replace the XAMPP data directory with the backup from your old MySQL one. Note that XAMPP may have "important stuff" in the database by default; I don't use it so I have no idea. You can also just drop in specific databases (which are represented on disk by files or folders of similar name), but will have to recreate permissions and users for those.

It's better to do SQL exports and imports for backing up your data.